# is it possible to create a trigger involving 3 tables and conditional statements?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

i have 3 tables in my database and they all are depend on each other

there is a project table

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id        | project name        |status (1 confirmed / 2 in progress / 3 done )   |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|   233     | project 1           |1                                                |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  234      | project 2           | 3                                               |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

table 2 is the category

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+ 
| id        | category            | confirmed_counter | inprogress_counter|done_counter       |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|         1 | c++                 |      2            |3                  | 1                 |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|         2 | php                 |      3            |4                  | 6                 |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

and table 3 is category objects

```
+-----------+---------------------+------------+ 
| id        | project_id          | category_id|
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|         1 | 233                 |      2     |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|         2 | 244                 |      3     |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
```

i want to create a trigger to update category's counters as the project status changes

when admin confirms a project , it's status will change to 1 so in the category table 
`confirmed_counter`  should increment
but first i have to look into category objects and see what is the category or Categories of that project and then update the counter field for those Categories

```
$c = $project->get_categorys();
///// it returns array of that project category ids ( 2 ,3 ,4)
$sql = update `categorys` set `confirmed_counter` = confirmed_counter+1 where `id` in (2,3,4);
```

and when a project  is in progress

```
$sql = update `categorys` set `confirmed_counter` = confirmed_counter-1 , `inprogress_counter` = inprogress_counter+1 where `id` in (2,3,4);
```

and when the project is done

```
$sql = update `categorys` set `inprogress_counter` = inprogress_counter-1 , `done_counter` = done_counter+1 where `id` in (2,3,4);
```

and it's not always in that order 
a project might get reset when it's in progress

so there is 2 important step before updating the counters

first i have to get the project's category id from third table

then i have to increase and decrease the counters based on the current and previous status of the project

is it possible to create a trigger to do this  ?

////////////////////////////////////////////////// edit ///////////////////////////////////

is it possible to instead of just assuming pervious status , specify that by using OLD in the code ?
like changing

```
  SET
    confirmed_counter = 
      CASE NEW.status
        WHEN 1 THEN confirmed_counter + 1
        WHEN 2 THEN confirmed_counter - 1
        ELSE confirmed_counter
      END,
```

to

```
  SET
    confirmed_counter = 
      CASE NEW.status
        WHEN 1 THEN confirmed_counter + 1
        ELSE confirmed_counter
      END,

    confirmed_counter = 
      CASE OLD.status
        WHEN 1 THEN confirmed_counter - 1
        ELSE confirmed_counter
      END,
```

i've tried to use it like this but always the last statement seems to be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it possible -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON project
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE category c
    JOIN category_objects co
      ON co.category_id = c.id
  SET
    confirmed_counter = 
      CASE NEW.status
        WHEN 1 THEN confirmed_counter + 1
        WHEN 2 THEN confirmed_counter - 1
        ELSE confirmed_counter
      END,
    inprogress_counter =
      CASE NEW.status
        WHEN 1 THEN inprogress_counter
        WHEN 2 THEN inprogress_counter + 1
        ELSE inprogress_counter - 1
      END,
    done_counter =
      CASE NEW.status
        WHEN 1 THEN done_counter
        WHEN 2 THEN done_counter
        ELSE done_counter + 1
      END
  WHERE
    co.project_id = NEW.id;
END
```

---

Example on second question:

```
...
confirmed_counter =
  CASE
    WHEN NEW.status = 1 THEN confirmed_counter + 1
    WHEN OLD.status = 1 THEN confirmed_counter - 1
    ELSE confirmed_counter
END
....
```

Comment: You can use second version of CASE statament - CASE WHEN [condition] THEN result [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END. More information - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html